# Should questions on tajweed be on-topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic

Should questions related to Tajweed be on-topic here on this site?

Has it got deeper connection with the study of Islam than Arabic?

And is the subject unique to the studies of Islam hence deserve to be on-topic here on Islam?

Reference questions:

- [What is a harakat and/or count?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/16911)
- [What is tajweed? Is it necessary to learn or is it just recommended?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/431)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tajwid is a uniquely Islamic science, more connected with recitation of the Qur'an than to Arabic itself (nothing other than Qur'an is spoken/recited with Tajwid). It is an integral part of the field of recitation and Qur'anic studies, and therefore questions about Tajwid should be squarely on-topic on Islam.SE .

Answer (score 0):

I think Tajweed for proper pronunciation of the Quranic verses by laymen can be considered an Islamic science and hence on-topic, but those rules of Tajweed which concern tunes and melodies used for professional recitation should be considered off-topic.

**Revision,post-scripted:**
Giving it a second thought I realized that melodies used in professional reciting of Quran do not make up part of Tajweed as Tajweed is only about pronunciation rules. So it is right to allow questions on Tajweed.

Comment: Why would the distinction between "for laymen" and "for professionals" make any difference? That is not usually where/how the line is drawn between subject matters or even expertise.

Comment: @Caleb, because I think recitation as a religious practice is part of Islam however professional recitation is some sort of an art and mainly for ceremonial purposes.

Comment: Aren't said same ceremonies Islamic ceremonies?  is it somehow not a religious practice if does professionally instead of amateur?

Comment: @Caleb, well, I think there are more about Islamic culture than Islam itself.

Comment: @Caleb, but now that I think again, melodies are not part of tajweed so it is entirely on-topic.