# A list of 24 questions about triple talaq

Tags: discussion, questions

Here's the current list of questions about *triple talaq*.  We get a lot.  I'm making this as a reference post, to link to authors who ask triple talaq questions (they can edit their questions based on previous answers) and to facilitate weeding out duplicates.

2012

1. [Just reciting "Talak" thrice commits divorce?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/103/17163)

2013

2. [After my husband wrote talaq three times, then said it three times, is our talaq valid?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/10144/17163)

2014

3. [What should be the wording of divorce?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/16266/17163)
4. [If a husband says 'talaq' to his wife jokingly, does 'talaq' happen?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/16610/17163)
5. [How does triple talaq work in conjunction with court?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/17972/17163)

2015

6. [Upon the wife's request during an argument, if a man gives his wife three talaqs at once, are they divorced?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/24661/17163)
7. [Does saying talaq in mind count as talaq?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/25745/17163)
8. [Wife's claim on Divorce](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/26053/17163)
9. [An irrational divorce given by husband during pregnancy](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/26161/17163)
10. [If my husband was unaware of the consequences of three talaqs, is still valid?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/26337/17163)
11. [After the husband saying "I give you talaq 3 times", pregnancy, and him leaving the country for two years, what is the status of their marriage?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/27494/17163)
12. [Does saying talaq twice over the phone in anger break a marriage?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/28974/17163) (deleted)
13. [One talaq is given to the woman 5 years ago, what to do now?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/28987/17163)

2016

14. [In anger, I signed a letter to my wife saying talaaq thrice; is this divorce valid?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/29845/17163)
15. [What should a wife do if the husband has given more then 3 talaq's and denying it according shari'a?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/30620/17163)
16. [I married after she got pregnant and now we have 3 talaqs](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/33496/17163)
17. [What is the correct procedure for talaq?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/36876/17163)

2017

18. [What are the conditions for talaq to be valid?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/37519/17163)
19. [Did a divorce happen by texting talaq three times?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/37894/17163)
20. [Triple Talaq in Islam](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/39736/17163) (closed as duplicate)
21. [More than three talaqs but in ignorance. Is the marriage valid? Can they remarry?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/39476/17163)
22. [If my husband divorced me twice but says he did it three times, are we still married?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/39491/17163)
23. [Does unwillingly saying "talaaq" three times count as divorce?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40236/17163)
24. [In the Hanafi view, after my husband said the triple talaq in anger, am I now divorced with no hope of reconciliation?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/40426/17163)

Answer (score 3):

Excellent compilation of list, and I guess it will grow with time. I always have a reservation about such questions, though. Islam.SE is [not a fatwa site](https://islam.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), yet lots of questions about triple talaq are contextual at best (applying to multiple people), or individual-based at worst (in terms of wide applicability). I understand that this is the intended current practice, but is it a practice honored more in the breach than in the observance?

Unlike sites like [Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/sendq) or [IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=fatwa&tab=3) where one question has only one answer (the nature of a fatwa web site) that presents one view, Islam.SE is about presenting multiple views and letting the community vote up good answers. This is not always the case, as voters abiding by the site rules vote up answers based on usefulness at large (not necessarily being the correct opinion), and those who do not abide will typically vote up answers that they tend to agree with. Fatwa sites, on the other hand, require that all eight views be studied (Abu Hanifa's and Hanafis, Malik's and Malikis, etc., as they do not necessarily always agree), then consult scientists on the topic if it has its own academic studies (e.g., doctors on DNA matters, economists on matters on market dealings, etc.), then form a single specific opinion (this is the absolute nature to give one view only, which some users seem to unknowingly take it against fatwa web sites), then present this view, preferable (but not a requirement) with supporting evidence.

My suggestion is that we add an off-topic category that is dedicated to Islam.SE not being a fatwa site. This should help us close questions that fall under the category of individual fatwas, while keeping ones that are broad enough or can be made broad enough through editing.

> Closing — Off topic
>
> Islam.SE is not a fatwa site. This question belongs a fatwa site as
>   the case has more than one condition that makes it specific to an
>   individual or under specific conditions, which requires a certified
>   scholar to answer.

In my opinion, two topics need to fall under this (will definitely be revised as we move along):

1. Matters related to individual marriage or divorce validity.
2. Matters related to the inheritance of one individual or a number of individuals tied together (e.g., parents die in an accident, while mother is pregnant but the fetus survives for a few hours in an incubator, who should inherit).

Comment: I'm in the process of proposing replacement close reasons.  [This post](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3033/17163) was a step towards that.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones, thanks. Copied the relevant portion to an answer to the other question. Hope I am not breaking any rules that I am unaware of :-).