# Can we make [pronunciation] a synonym of [tajweed]?

Tags: discussion, tag, tag-synonyms

Questions about the Arabic language and/or [pronunciation](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronunciation) are off topic: [Should we allow questions regarding the Arabic language?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11/should-we-allow-questions-regarding-the-arabic-language)

But questions about [tajweed](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tajweed) *are* on-topic: [Should questions on tajweed be on-topic?](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1321/should-questions-on-tajweed-be-on-topic)

Can we make one [pronunciation](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronunciation) a synonym of [tajweed](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tajweed), and update the description of [tajweed](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tajweed) to reflect that it's *only* for tajweed and not general pronunciation?

Comment: We had lately a question on that for which such a duplicate wouldn't apply. It is even discussed in one of the latest meta posts ;). IMHO a tag pronunciation actually shouldn't even be used in the context of IslamSE at all, because it is rather a linguistic topic.

Comment: @Medi1Saif that's what inspired this post in fact. By making it a synonym, and updating the 'usage' part of the tag it would warn people not to use it for every-day pronunciations. We can remove it from the posts it no longer applies to separately

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer of your linked post says:

> Tajwid is a uniquely Islamic science, **more connected with recitation of the Qur'an than to Arabic itself** (**nothing other than Qur'an is spoken/recited with Tajwid**). It is an integral part of the field of recitation and Qur'anic studies, and therefore questions about Tajwid should be squarely on-topic on Islam.SE .

This shows that tajweed of qur'an and Arabic pronounciation don't fully match and can't be synonyms.

Comment: To be fair, the actual words don't need to be synonymous for the *tags* to be synonyms. If you're worried about confusion, you could specifically add `quran-pronunciation` as a synonym instead. (Also, in looking at the tag list, it looks like `quran-recitation` and `reading-quran` already exist as tags... I'm not enough of an expert to tell whether they're being used to refer to the same concept as `tajweed`, but the community can make that determination and possibly synonymize them if appropriate.)